# Trouble working with date returned by dayClick

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm new to FullCalendar and relatively new to js/jquery, so apologize if this is an easy question.  I'm trying unsuccessfully to work with the date returned by FullCalendar's `dayClick`.

I'm hoping to grab it, add a day to create a second date, and use both when constraining an ajax call to google calendar API to fetch one day's calendar events.

My most recent attempt is at the jsfiddle linked here: http://jsfiddle.net/gbkester/a1zhhv6z/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
        editable: true,
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log(date)
            dy = date.getDay()
            console.log(dy)
            dt = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 0, 0, 0)
            console.log(dt)
            dt2 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay() + 1, 0, 0, 0)
            console.log(dt2)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/)

```
function( date, jsEvent, view ) { }
```

> date holds a Moment for the clicked day

This means that FullCalendar uses [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to manipulate all things related to dates. As you may see from the documentation of Moment.js, it has several methods available.

If you set your `dayClick` function to something like this, it will work:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var dt = date.toDate();
    // OR, if you want a specific format
    //var dt = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    console.log(dt);

    dt2 = date.add(1, 'day');
    console.log(dt2.toDate());
}
```